# Using Bootstrap, I can only get the text to act like a link, not the whole button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, twitter-bootstrap

I'm just learning how to use html and css and my teacher has asked us to use Bootstrap. It's really cool, obviously, but when I try to make a button, only the text within the button actually acts like a link as opposed to the whole rectangular button. I'm not sure if I need more than just the minified bootstrap javascript file to make them work or what.

Here's my html, and I also added the line "$('.nav-tabs').button()" to my head as well as the javascript file from bootstrap. Any advice? I know my html is probably pretty janky, my teacher isn't the best at explaining things so I've just been fiddling with things until they seem to work.

```
<div class="btn-toolbar">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span2 offset2">
        <div class="btn btn-primary">
            <a href="http://students.cec.wustl.edu/~amd4/Portfolio/portfolio%20-%20profile%20-%20final.html">
                Profile
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span2 offset.5">
        <div class="btn">
            <a href="http://students.cec.wustl.edu/~amd4/Portfolio/portfolio%20-%20writing%20-%20final.html">
                Writing
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span2 offset.5">
        <div class="btn">
            <a href="http://students.cec.wustl.edu/~amd4/Portfolio/portfolio%20-%20music%20-%20final.html">
                Music
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span2 offset.5">
        <div class="btn">
            <a href="http://students.cec.wustl.edu/~amd4/Portfolio/portfolio%20-%20photos%20-%20final.html">
                Photography
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are not adding the class on the `a` tag.
You need to use something like this `<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">New button</a>` This should give you a button with the text New button.

You use  `<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Big Button</a>`

For a large blue button.

Answer (score 2):

remove the `class="btn btn-primary"` from the `div` tag, put it on the `a` tag

see http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#buttons

> ...typically you'll want to apply these to only `<a>` and `<button>` elements for the best rendering.